# Remove ProducesResponseType attribute webapi aspnetcore 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I m currently doing as below and adding ProducesResponseType attribute in order to produce better api documentation

```
    [HttpGet(Name=nameof(MyNewMethodAsync)
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClassResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClassResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyClassResponse), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    [SwaggerOperation(nameof(MyNewMethodAsync))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyClassResponse>> MyNewMethodAsync([FromQuery] MyClassRequest request)
    {}
```

are we saying that the above could be simplified with no need for ProducesResponseType and equivalent to below:

```
    [HttpGet(Name=nameof(MyNewMethodAsync)      
    [SwaggerOperation(nameof(MyNewMethodAsync))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyClassResponse>> MyNewMethodAsync([FromQuery] MyClassRequest request)
    {}
```

What about if I  wanted to put a better description regarding for each HttpStatusCode

Many thanks

Comment: I just want confirmations that .net core 2.1  removes the need for attributes

Comment: No it doesn't. But better put, they were never necessary to begin with. It's always been about documenting possible return types, which cannot necessarily be ascertained from the method definition itself. If you need the documentation of a particular return type, then you need the attribute as well (assuming again, that something like Swagger can't programmatically determine it on its own).

Comment: 2.1 *did* remove the need to specify the return *type*, though, as it can now get this information via `ActionResult<T>`. However, you still need to specify the possible response status codes.

Comment: yes I need it for documentation but my understanding is that "ActionResult<yourclass>" will do the magic and no more attribute but not sure what I do about the question now

Comment: I think you answered my question now. I wanted to know the possible response types if they were still necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, yes the `ProducesResponseType` attribute is necessary if all possible response status codes cannot be ascertained based on the method definition. For example, 200 is obvious, but if you actually need to return 201, that would need to be specified. Same for 404, etc. I'm not honestly sure about 400, since 2.1 now automatically checks `ModelState.IsValid`, so this may now be a default response type, but if not, then you'd need an attribute for that too. The only thing 2.1 buys you really here, is no longer needing to actually specify the return type itself, just the status code.

Comment: If for BadRequest I am returning MyerrorResponse class, and for 200 MyClassResponse, I still need to specify return type for BadRequest, is not it?